# Can not scale service to multiple container when binding host port in docker-compose.yml

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

Micro service is running on one container. I have bound that service to Host port `8082` and launched this micro service using `docker-compose`. Now I want to scale it to 3 container using `docker-compose scale` command but it giving me following error-

> ERROR: for 2  failed to create endpoint composetest_nginx_2 on network
>   composetest_default: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8082 failed: port is already
>   allocated
>
> ERROR: for 3  failed to create endpoint composetest_nginx_3 on network
>   composetest_default: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8082 failed: port is already
>   allocated

What would be the solution for this?

Answer (score 27):

I solved it by passing a port range, with the correct syntax :P

```
ports:
      - "9110-9120:3333"
```

Comment: this doesn't work. `Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5002: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.`

Comment: Which version of docker compose were you using? This is failing for me using docker compose 3.

I have this in my config file:
```
services:
  myservice:
    image: xxx
    ports:
      - "7900-7910:7900"
```

And when I execute ```docker-compose up -d --scale myservice=3```

I got this error: ```Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:7900 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:7900: bind: address already in use```

Comment: Same for me, any solution for this case?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Docker Compose version v2.12.2. I'm specifying a port range similar to above. One container gets created but then shows the same 'bind address already in use' error as above. 
Any updates on this please?

Comment: This tries to bind both containers to more than one port and only one of the containers win to be bind with the given ports.

Answer (score 15):

You are not supposed to bind 3 containers' ports to the same port in host.

What you can do is setting up:

- 1 load balancer container (bind container's port XXXX to host's port 8082)
- 3 service containers (expose ports to load balancer)

`bind` only binds 1 port to host. And `expose` only exposes ports to the linked container so they can be from multiple containers.

Reference:

https://www.brianchristner.io/how-to-scale-a-docker-container-with-docker-compose/

https://github.com/vegasbrianc/docker-compose-demo/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: how to give multiple ports in ports:
      - 8080     otherwise  random host ports are assigned to 8080

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Nginx or similar, then you can use `docker-gen` command to auto-update configurations in Nginx.

See this for more info: https://deployeveryday.com/2016/09/28/composing-docker-environments-scale.html

Answer (score 0):

the way to do it is to remove the source port.
for example, change

```
ports:
    - "5000:5000"
```

to

```
ports:
    - "5000"
```

the downside is you don't know the range of the port number until the service started.

Answer (score -12):

Good option is to give range port rather giving specific port in docker-compose...

```
ports:
 - 8081+:8081
```

This way it will allow you to do scaling your service without getting into the issue you mentioned (**Port already allocated**) as Host port will different for each scaled instance & Docker will handle that for you...

Comment: Throws an invalid exception for that syntax.

Comment: wish this could work though